# Using a VPC for API Gateway and RDS | AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am new to AWS. I have a **REST API I built with Django and want to deploy it on AWS API Gateway**. I also have that connecting to a **PostgreSQL database on AWS RDS**.

I've heard that it is **more secure to put both in a VPC**. But, I don't really know how that makes it more secure. **What does putting them both in a VPC actually do?** Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably don't want anyone to access the DB directly, with VPC you can lock down the DB to only be available to your API. In addition, while your API needs to be accessible from the internet anyway, you can have robust logging, traffic filtering, and access control that run separately from the application. That is, even if the application framework turns out to have a security hole, the VPC rules *might* be able to mitigate them, and even when the attacker managed to get into the API controller and wreak havoc, the logging exists separately and still works. Depending on your configuration, it can even alert you for unforeseen traffic.

Comment: Got it! So the main point is that I can make it so that the DB can only be access coming from my API? Do you know how AWS WAF fits into all of this?

Comment: WAF deals with the traffic before they enter your VPC. So they're geared toward covering parts of your API that can't be covered by VPC (eg, you can lock down some administration interface on your API through VPC, but if you want to avoid exploits through valid, publicly available ports & URL, then it's WAF job)